# SQL Aging Report

Tags: sql

I have the following data transactions for Account Receivables:

[image: initial data]

I need to get an Aging Report by every 3 days, so the script should take the last payment or credit and apply it to the very last charge. So the result would be something like this:

[image]

Here the $245 credit is applied to the very last $400 charge, so the remaining balance of that charge will be $155. Then, the script should take the next last payment and apply it following the same rules like this:

[image]

Here the $1300 payment is applied to the remaning $155 balance of April 2nd and then the $1,145 remaining is applied to the 1,300 charge of date July 1st so the ending balance is $155 resulting in this:

[image]

So, now I know that the Final Balance is $673.21 but I also know that between 0-16 days I have an outstanding balance of 518.21 and between 17-30 days I have an outstanding balance of 155.

Any clue on how to do a SQL Query in order to get this result?

Thanks a lot!! And appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be different ways to do this in different databases. I created a table with your values in Firebird 2.5 (only added an ID column and changed names due to reserved words) and ran this statement:

```
with recursive tmp_payment (paid) as
(select -sum(amount)
 from account_receivables
 where amount < 0),
MyResultSet(id, MyBalance, RemainingCredit, Days) as
(select r.id, case when r.amount > p.paid then r.amount-p.paid end, 
        case when r.amount < 0 then p.paid
             when r.amount < p.paid then p.paid-r.amount 
             else 0 end, current_date - MyDate
 from account_receivables r
 cross join tmp_payment p
 where not exists(select 1 from account_receivables r2 where r2.id < r.id)
 union all
 select r3.id, case when r3.amount > rs.RemainingCredit then r3.amount - rs.RemainingCredit end,
        case when r3.amount < 0 then rs.RemainingCredit 
             when r3.amount < rs.RemainingCredit then rs.RemainingCredit - r3.amount 
        else 0 end,
        current_date - MyDate
 from ACCOUNT_RECEIVABLES r3
 join MyResultSet rs on r3.id = rs.id+1)

Select id, MyBalance, Days
from MyResultSet
union all
select null, (select sum(MyBalance) from MyResultSet), null
from rdb$database
```

Apart from rdb$database, which is simply a table that is guaraneed to only contain one record in Firebird and InterBase, and possibly CURRENT_DATE (obvious meaning), this should be quite standard SQL, although far from all databases support WITH RECURSIVE (required for the MyResultSet, tmp_Payment is not recursive) and some may have different ways to subtract one date from another.

This is what the statement returned:

```
  ID   MYBALANCE DAYS
   1     <NULL>   110
   2     <NULL>    21
   3     155.00    20
   4     518.21    16
   5     <NULL>    16
<NULL>   673.21 <NULL>
```

Comment: What I ended up is to do a WHILE @paid > 0 statement in SQL with a TEMP table. Think was easier and faster. What do you think?